# how to exclude equal column in django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model with 2 foreign filed point to the same model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    old_school = model.ForeignField(school)
    new_school = model.ForeignField(school)
```

I want to find student who's old_school != new_school. I tried these:

```
Student.objects.all().exlude(old_school = new_school)
Student.objects.all().exlude(self.old_school = self.new_school)
```

but none of them work. It seems model manager can not refer to new_school. Is there any method to do such query? Or I have to manually check not equal in python code:

```
if student.old_school != student.new_school:
   s_list.append(student)
```

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: Oh, my real problem is about product stock location, I want to find product returning to supplier. I just simplify the original problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) and [`F`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model):

```
Student.objects.filter(~Q(old_school=F('new_school')))
```

`Q` helps to build `not equal` condition, while `F` helps to reference another model field.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished without the Q object if you want to import one less thing.

```
from django.db.models import F

Student.objects.exclude(old_school=F('new_school'))
```

In my testing it generated the same MySQL on the backend.